# Sum of the generalized convolution product of two signals

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, signal-processing

I am trying to prove this property, which states that the sum of the generalized convolution of two product,
$$\sum_{n=1}^N (f*g)(n)=\sqrt{N}\hat{f}(0)\hat{g}(0)$$
The property is found on the article "Vertex-frequency analysis on graphs".
I tried proving by definition, where
$$\sum_{n=1}^N (f*g)(n)=\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{\ell=0}^{N-1}\hat{f}(\lambda_\ell)\hat{g}(\lambda_\ell)\chi_\ell(n)$$.
I also converted the inner summation by getting the fourier transform of it, so I have now
$$\sum_{n=1}^N (f*g)(n)=\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)g(n)$$
After this, I don't know how to proceed. I just know that $\sqrt{N}$ has something to do with the eigenvalues. Any ideas?

Comment: The DC sample of the Fourier transform is just the sum of the time-domain samples (usually scaled by $\sqrt{N}$ or $N$ depending on the definition being used). This fact coupled with the convolution/multiplication property is all you need to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

I get it now, I realized the process I did above was wrong. Here's my answer to the problem.
$$\sum_{n=1}^N (f*g)(n)=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{\ell=0}^{N-1}\hat{f}(\lambda_\ell)\hat{g}(\lambda_\ell)\chi_\ell (n)$$
After that we multiply $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ to both sides. We now have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^N (f*g)(n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{\ell=0}^{N-1}\hat{f}(\lambda_\ell)\hat{g}(\lambda_\ell)\chi_\ell (n)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\ell=0}^N\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\hat{f}(\lambda_\ell)\hat{g}(\lambda_\ell)\chi_\ell (n)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\ell=1}^{N-1}\hat{f}(\lambda_\ell)\hat{g}(\lambda_\ell)\sum_{n=1}^{N}\chi_\ell (n)$$
Since given from the article that $\chi_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$, we have now,
$$=\sum_{\ell=0}^{N-1}\hat{f}(\lambda_\ell)\hat{g}(\lambda_\ell)\sum_{n=1}^{N}\chi_0\chi_\ell (n)$$
The inner summation defines a orthonormal basis, that is, the dot product is equal to 0 if $0\neq\ell$ otherwise 1; and given than $\lambda_0=0$. Hence we have,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^N (f*g)(n)=\hat{f}(0)\hat{g}(0)$$.
Finally, simplifying we get the equation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N (f*g)(n)=\sqrt{N}\hat{f}(0)\hat{g}(0)$$